# Python and Perl not recognized in cmd even after adding in environment

Tags: command-line, python, cmd.exe, environment-variables, perl

It was fine yesterday, but it suddenly stopped working today.

Both my perl and python were not recognized in cmd. I read as much as i can online for the answers and follow the instruction. I have also tried re-installing python a few times.

What did I do wrong?

[image: screenshot env & cmd]

Comment: The python path doesn't have `bin` on it, can you run python if you go to the bin directory? Also it looks like perl should be working. can you verify the .exe files exist in the path provided ?

Comment: should there be a bin in the python folder? I checked with my other laptop that works, it also doesn't have bin in the python folder. how do i verify? I believe python (application) is the .exe file for python.

Comment: My perl also is not working..

Comment: I see, does going to the folder and running python/perl work?

Comment: in cmd, I went into python38-32 and run python.exe, it works.

Comment: Have you restarted your computer and tried?